# Angular2 ngFor for multiple selectboxes. Next select gets the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I created a view in which it should be possible to select multiple persons. From the same list of persons. (I don't want to use a multiselect)

What I don't seem to get is: when selecting a value in selectbox 1 the value of next selectbox is being set. Why does this happen?

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <select *ngFor="let selectedPerson of selectedPeople; let i = index;" (change)="selectChanged(i, $event.target.value)">
            <option></option>
            <option *ngFor="let person of people" [value]="person.id">{{ person.name }}</option>
        </select>

        <pre>{{ people | json }}</pre>
    `
})
export class AppComponent { 
    public people = <IPerson[]>[
        {id: 1, name: "Mike"},
        {id: 2, name: "Jacob"},
        {id: 3, name: "Ralph"},
        {id: 4, name: "name4"},
        {id: 5, name: "name5"},
        {id: 6, name: "name6"},
        {id: 7, name: "name7"},
    ];
    public selectedPeople[];

    constructor(){
        this.selectedPeople = Array(6).fill(<IPerson>{ });
    }

    selectChanged(index, value){
        let person = this.people.find((person: IPerson) => person.id == value);

        this.selectedPeople[index] = person;
    }
}

export interface IPerson{
    id: number,
    name: string
}
```

Edit:

The line `this.selectedPeople[index] = person;` causes this issue..

Comment: I would suggest updating to `v2.1` first. By the looks of it, you are still using an alpha version

Comment: Thanks, just did that. Sadly it does not fix the issue..

Comment: That's a fast update. I would expect updating an app all the way from alpha to release would take a lot longer. But guess your app isn't that big yet :)

Comment: I have the issue in a bigger app. But before asking on stack I tested it in a other empty ng2 project. (didn't notice that the empty project was the wrong version) So I cheated a little.. and created a new project (with the right version)

Comment: seems like a bug in view, since the model is not affected by this issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/tu8AqTRJEBhJFHMpBAvM?p=preview maybe we can find a workaround...

Comment: Thanks! I would like that, been struggling for 2 days now..

Comment: I found a solution, it's not as pretty as I would like but it works. I used the package "typescript-collections" (https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections) to create a key value dictionary. If you, or someone else in the future comes up with something better I would be very interested!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `*ngFor` on a select apparently causes strange issues. You should wrap your `select` inside a `div`.

```
<div *ngFor="let selectedPerson of selectedPeople; let i = index;">
    <select (change)="selectChanged(i, $event.target.value)" [value]="selectedPerson.id">
       <option></option>
       <option *ngFor="let person of people" [value]="person.id">{{ person.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<pre>{{ people | json }}</pre>
```

I am not sure this is can be considered a bug in angular2 or it's because of the templating done when using `*` expressions.

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work. but the behaviour is a bit different. When chaning selectbox 1 the value is set correct. But the value of the second select is changed to..

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML as below and check :

```
<select *ngFor="let selectedPerson of selectedPeople;let i = index;" (change)="selectChanged(i, $event.target.value)">
  <option></option>
  <option *ngFor="let person of people" [attr.selected]="selectedPerson === person.id" [value]="person.id">{{ person.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It did not help though :(

Comment: Still the same behaviour. Thinking out loud here: could it be possible that `this.selectedPeople[index] = person;` changes the order of the array or something?

Comment: May be, you can check it by printing its value in view like `<pre>{{ selectedPeople | json }}</pre>` as you have done for person.